# Changing the parent of a component in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have a situation where i have a component (say a timer ticking down) . On firing a specific trigger say a button click or page scroll, i want to change the Wrapper Component of `<Timer/>` component from the div with id `dummyWrapper` to div with id `newParent`. Is there any React specific way to achieve this?

By using portals, the element is mounted and unmounted thereby losing the current "state" of the timer.

Using `document.getElementById(`newParent`).appendChild(TimerWrapper)` seems to work, but im not sure if this is a good approach.

Sample DOM Structure:

```html
<App>
<div id="newParent"/>
<Child />
</App>

const Child = () => {
return <div> <div id="dummyWrapper"> <Timer/>  </div>
}
```

Comment: You can define some variable in `state` and then after button clicked - change the `state` value. And show/hide blocks depends on the state (or add/remove some class on parent div and depends on this class show different blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You need to hoist the state from the child component into the parent.

With react you need to move away from direct dom manipulation using document.getElementById, jQuery, etc. The single source of truth for your app needs to exist solely in react.

```
const App = () => {
  const [timerAdded, setTimerAdded] = useState(false)
  return (
    <>
      <div id="newParent">
        {
          timerAdded && <TimerWrapper />
        }
      </div>
      <Child setTimerAdded={setTimerAdded} />
    <>
  )
}

const Child = ({setTimerAdded}) => {
  return <div> <div id="dummyWrapper" onClick={setTimerAdded}> <Timer/>  </div>
}
const Timer = () => { return <span>Tick Tock </span>}
```